# $(n,m,d)-$code Hamming bound

Tags: discrete-mathematics, coding-theory

I have the $(n,m,d)-$ code $(6,4,4)$ which can clearly be constructed

$$\begin{pmatrix} 000000 \\111100 \\ 001111 \\ 110011  \end{pmatrix}$$

However, if i try using the hamming bound on $m$ i have,

$$m \leq \frac{2^6}{1+\sum^t_{i=1} {n \choose i} }$$ 
I get the upper bound for $t$ to be $2$, as $$d \geq 2t +1$$
this tells me $m$ must be less than or equal to $2.9$ could someone explain what i'm doing wrong?

Comment: For $t=2$ you have a $(6,m,5)$ code as $d\ge 2t+1 = 5$. Thus $t=1$.

Comment: surely when i rearrange and plug in $d$ i have $1.5 \geq t$ hence $t=1.5$? would i not choose $t=2$ as this is the upper bound?

Answer (score 0):

If $d \geq 2t+1$ then
\begin{align*}
t & \leq \lfloor (d-1)/2 \rfloor & \text{since $t$ is a positive integer} \\
&= \lfloor 3/2 \rfloor & \text{since $d=4$} \\
& =1.
\end{align*}

So the [Hamming Bound](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamming_bound) is $$m \leq \frac{2^6}{1+\binom{6}{1}} \simeq 9.14$$ which is consistent with $m=4$.